# blockquote-reverse in Bootstrap-4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

What is the replacement of `blockquote-reverse` class of Bootstrap-3 in Bootstrap-4. I googled it but could not find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap 4.x removed classnames like this in favor of their new utility classes. This is noted in their [migration documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/#typography) when searching for `blockquote-reverse`

> Redesigned blockquotes, moving their styles from the `<blockquote>`
>   element to a single class, `.blockquote`. Dropped the
>   `.blockquote-reverse` modifier for text utilities.

The new text utility classes provide a much more granular control over how the contents is organized - but for the purposes of replicating `.blockquote-reverse` you need only apply `text-right`.

[Bootstrap 4.x Text Utility Class Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/text/)

Answer (score 1):

In version 4 they replaced `blockquote-reverse` with `blockquote text-right`

Try this code sample,

```
<blockquote class="blockquote text-right">
  <p class="mb-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
  <footer class="blockquote-footer">Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite></footer>
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use class="pull-right" to pull everything including the associating line to the right. class="text-right" only aligns the text and not the gray line associated with blockquote.